# Using ColumnArg in OrmLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, orm, ormlite

[`ColumnArg`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_3.html#Column-Arguments) is a great addition to OrmLite which allows comparing columns when using a `QueryBuilder`.

I have the following use case, which is virtually identical to the example given on the OrmLite site (return all `Foo`s where `alpha <> beta` (where `alpha` and `beta` are some columns in the database):

```
Dao<Foo, Integer> fooDao = databaseHelper.getDao(Foo.class);
QueryBuilder<Foo, Integer> fooQB = fooDao.queryBuilder();
fooQB.where().ne("alpha", new ColumnArg("beta")); // where alpha <> beta
List<Foo> result = fooQB.query();
```

The problem I've found is that regardless of whether alpha and beta columns are not equal, they are **always** returned by this query.

After double-checking the SQLite database contents and running the query directly against the database from the command line, I decided I'd better chack what statement is actually being produced by the `QueryBuilder`:

```
Log.d("Foo", "Query: " + fooQB.prepareStatementString());
```

The underlying query is then exposed to be:

```
SELECT * FROM `foos` WHERE `alpha` <> 'com.j256.ormlite.stmt.ColumnArg@419fb770'
```

What seems to be happening here is that OrmLite is not reading the second argument of `ne()` as a `ColumnArg` but is instead getting the `toString()` representation of the `ColumnArg` and treating it as the column **value** (string).

The correct query should clearly be:

```
SELECT * FROM `foos` WHERE `alpha` <> `beta`
```

Is this a bug in OrmLite or am I using `ColumnArg` incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> SELECT * FROM `foos` WHERE `alpha` <> 'com.j256.ormlite.stmt.ColumnArg@419fb770'

Wow.  Just wow.  This is just a bad bug in ORMLite.  In looking at the code I'm embarrassed.  I should have seen that it would happen when I added the `ColumnArg` functionality.

I've checked a fix into trunk which you can get via git:

> https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core/commit/60676a74cebf4704f2eee0d1ec05207a83a706d1

It will be in the 4.46 release of ORMLite.

Comment: Thanks for the super-quick reply Gray -- and an incredibly fast bugfix. I reckoned this *had* to be a bug since my code was just so close to the example that there was no room for error!